# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: php, web, syntax-error

I've been building a web app, but I have a problem. If I run my web app on `localhost` it works, but when I uploaded it to `cpanel`, it didn't work.

Error:

> Failed to load resource:  net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS.

How to solve this problem? Help.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a proper issue explanation

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when you are not calling an internet permission into your app. Try adding this code into your xml Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Please look at the question's tags - it's a PHP question, so an answer specifically for Android won't help.